# Chinese (.cn) api calls .com AutocompletionService which results in failure

Tags: google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

In order to make autocomplete work in China I referenced Chinese Google Maps Api, as suggested in the [documentation](http://maps.google.cn/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false).

When it's called to get autocomplete results, I see it correctly makes requests to:
http://maps.google.cn/maps/api/js/AuthenticationService.Authenticate?...

... but then it makes a call to:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/AutocompletionService.GetPredictions?...

... which is unable to be completed when website is used in China because this domain is blocked in China.

See [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/tCqIPbu1the6Nrm3Rgic?p=preview) (press F12, open Network tab, and watch requests as you type in the input).
Apparently SO questions with links to plunkr require code, so here is a reference to the script I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.cn/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
```

Here is a screenshot that shows the issue:
[image: wrong service is called when using .cn script]

Here is a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7627), submitted to Google, which apparently looks all good to them.

Am I doing something wrong? Can someone please confirm they see the same behavior as I do?

Comment: I encountered this behavior today examining our site from China, and ended up with the same problem you did. I'll be curious as to how you solved it.

Comment: the bug submitted to google remains unresolved. I had to write some code to test if google service responds. If not - I just let input be a regular text input. [View relevant code](https://github.com/DmitryEfimenko/ngAutocomplete/blob/master/ngAutocomplete.js#L103-L114) if you'd like

Comment: From my early testing, this problem still exists as of Jan 2018. I cannot yet find a solution.